# Format a french phone number

Tags: android, string-formatting, number-formatting, phone-number

I have to format "0612345678" to "06 12 34 56 78".
I'm currently using this :

```
private String FormatTel(String number) {
    try {
        String formattedNumber = "";
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
            formattedNumber += number.substring(i, i + 2) + " ";
        }
        return formattedNumber.substring(0, formattedNumber.length() - 1);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return number;
    }
}
```

It only works on my emulator which is running the API 16 (JellyBean 4.1.1) : on it, the result looks like what I want ("06 12 34 56 78") but on my own phone, (API 22, Lollipop 5.1.1), it doesn't work : the result is "0 61 23 45 67" whereas the method is the SAME !

I did some research and I've found the String.Format method. But it's here I need help, it's too hard for me... !

Thank you in advance :D

**Edit :**

Working method, using libphonenumber :

```
private String FormatTel(String number) {
    String formattedNumber = number;
    try {
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber numberProto;
        numberProto = phoneNumberUtil.parse(number, "FR");
        formattedNumber = phoneNumberUtil.format(numberProto, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return formattedNumber;
}
```

Thank to **Ye Lin Aung** !

Comment: You may have mistyped on your phone, you are missing an 8

Comment: You might also want to use a StringBuilder

Comment: It can't be a problem with the number, because I use a text file and it's also the same for the two tests. But as Ye Lin Aung said, I'll use libphonenumber ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code on my Lollipop phone and it works as you expect.

Alternatively, I'd always suggest to use [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) to parse the phone numbers easily whenever it comes to do anything with phone number. Here's how it could be done.

```
try {
  PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
  Phonenumber.PhoneNumber numberProto;
  numberProto = phoneUtil.parse("+330612345678", "");
  Log.i("code",
      "code " + phoneUtil.format(numberProto, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL));
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which will result

```
 I/code﹕ code 06 12 34 56 78
```

Comment: I heard about this library, but I thought it didn't work for French phone numbers...

Comment: @Drarig29 it even works for a country like Myanmar (which is obviously less well known than France), you might want to give it a try again in their online demo at http://libphonenumber.appspot.com.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple regular expression.
`"0612345678".replaceAll("(.{2})", "$1 ");`

Here we are trying to groups of two characters and then replace each group with value of that group plus one space.

- `()` denotes a group
- `.{2}` Any two characters

`$x` will pick the xth group.

Note: This will add an extra space at the end, you may need to trim the string.

Comment: I prefer use the library (libphonenumber), sorry... Thank for the help !

Comment: No problem, regular expressions are so powerful, you can use it in many cases and you can avoid writing 10 lines of code with single regex. Have them in your toolkit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] charArray = YourString.toCharArray();
String finalString = "";
for(int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++) {
    if(i!=0 && i%2==0)
        finalString += " " + charArray[i];
    else
        finalString += charArray[i];
}
```

Blow up the string into a char array and then add as you go along. Should work okay. You also don't have to trim it at the end.

Comment: I prefer use the library (libphonenumber), sorry... Thank for the help !